# Pandas: Get index number based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

how can I grab the index number of a dataframe only if the values of a column match the values of another column in another df?

For instance, if I have a df_1 with a column of some words and in the other columns some values, and a df_2  with a list of words in a column and some other columns with other values, how can I grab the index numbers of the words in df_1, only if they match a word in df_2, and cast them into a list?

As an example, this could be my df_1

```
    W   X   Y   Z   Word
A   0.302665    1.693723    -1.706086   -1.159119   Abundant
B   -0.134841   0.390528    0.166905    0.184502    Boring
C   0.807706    0.072960    0.638787    0.329646    Careful
D   -0.497104   -0.754070   -0.943406   0.484752    Damage
E   -0.116773   1.901755    0.238127    1.996652    Energy
```

And this my df_2

```
    W   X   Y   Z   Header
0   1.668068    0.925862    1.057997    -0.920339   Adorable
1   1.299748    0.331183    -0.509845   -0.903099   Boring
2   -0.130016   -2.238203   0.973165    -0.024185   Cartoon
3   -0.484928   -1.109264   -0.558975   1.042387    Damage
4   -1.712263   0.136120    -0.464444   0.050980    Energy
```

Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you would need to pre-filter the df and then use `.index.tolist()` to get the index values as a list.

```
output = df_1[df_1['Word'].isin(df_2['Word'].values)].index.tolist()
```

The first part of the code is keeping only the rows in which the `Word` value exists in both dataframes, then, we select the index as mentioned before.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, the only thing that I noticed is that now I only have the df_1 index number. Is there a way to have them listed as df_2 index numbers? I tried to swap the df order in the code but the matches are not 1:1

Comment: If the results are not 1:1 then what would you like as outcome? It should work all the same